# Linux : Display a permanent text on the desktop

Tags: linux, desktop, display

I am looking for a way to display a permanent text on the desktop (xfce/gnome but if I found a way on another window manager, I catch).
I was asked to show a version number on the desktop in a permanent way, so I have to display it on opening session, and I have to update it if our software is updated.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to run any Xwindow application in the root window, however a simpler solution would be to use a wallpaper and set up a cron job to update the wallpaper file from a template using a script. You can add text (for example) using the [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/) toolkit or using [the GD extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) with PHP.

It's possible to [force XFCE](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=5535) to reload the wallpaper.

Answer (score 1):

in gnome you can set a global background using

```
gconftool-2 --direct \
--config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/opt/gnome/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory \
--type string --set /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename 
/usr/share/wallpapers/default-1600x1200.jpg
```

[source](http://wiki.ledhed.net/index.php/Gnome_Lockdown#Set_Global_Background_Image)

You could use [convert](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_convert.htm) to generate the wallpaper at login as explained [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Add-text-to-images-with-Linux-convert-command/#step1)
Remove the option to change the wallpaper

You could then use a script like

```
version= `uname -a`
convert -pointsize 10 -fill blue -draw 'text 800,6000 "version" ' basewallpaper.jpg usr/share/wallpapers/default-1600x1200.jpg
```